# How to update variable with random.randint in python?

Tags: python, global-variables, genetic

I have some code for a GA, that starts like this

```
import random

#
# Global variables
# Setup optimal string and GA input variables.


POP_SIZE    = random.randint(100,200) 

# random code that doesn't really matter...

# Simulate all of the generations.
  for generation in xrange(GENERATIONS):
    print "Generation %s... Random sample: '%s'" % (generation, population[0])
    print POP_SIZE 
    weighted_population = []
```

The important part is `print POP_SIZE`.

It prints what it needs to, and then the `POP_SIZE` stays the same, but is randomized 
ONLY if I exit the program and start it up again.

I want it to vary betweeen the paramaters I set at the beginning, which was

```
POP_SIZE    = random.randint(100,200)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Move it into the for loop? Right now you're generating a random number once...

Comment: Doesn't POP_SIZE need to be in the loop to get recalculated each time?  Am I missing something?

Comment: make an answer of it, @David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `print POP_SIZE`, you could `print POP_SIZE()` where:

```
def POP_SIZE():
    return random.randint(100,200)
```

Each time you call `POP_SIZE()` it will return a new random integer.

```
for generation in xrange(GENERATIONS):
    ...
    print POP_SIZE()
    ...
```

Comment: humm... when I try that it just says "    for i in xrange(POP_SIZE):
TypeError: an integer is required"

Comment: yeah, but I don't want to go back and replace POP_SIZE with POP_SIZE() everywhere... 

so i rewrote it like this 

    import random

    #
    # Global variables
    # Setup optimal string and GA input variables.
    #

    OPTIMAL     = "My name is billy bob and i like cheese"
    DNA_SIZE    = len(OPTIMAL)
    def random_function():
        return random.randomint(100,200)
    POP_SIZE    = random_function()
    GENERATIONS = 200

and now im getting this error 
"line 11, in random_function
    return random.randomint(100,200)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'randomint'"

Comment: Sorry, i dont know how to format the code... please don't down vote this, im trying to figure all this out.

Comment: The last error you get is because you used the wrong name. It's `randint` not `randomint`. Anyway if you don't want to use a function than you are stuck with a single random number.

Comment: @user1742566 you should add your solution as an answer :)

Comment: @user1742566 that's because you are trying to pass a function (?) into xrange (and it requires an integer).